# if change model-class in DbContext, do I rebuild the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have my App in MVC with DBContext, in my localhost in SQL, my DB have data. Then I need add a new Column in one Table, add my new member in my model-class and I modified my Table in SQL but when I execute my App: ".. context has changed ... Consider using code first migrations ..."

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

If you followed the **required** steps, you can run "update database" from the "Package Manager Console".

Example:

1. Make Required Code Change
2. From the *Package Manager Console*: Run **Add-Migration** *[Migration Name]*
3. Make any neccessary changes to the generated code.
4. From the *Package Manager Console*: Run **Update-Database**

Comment: Yes, I have done it so also but, do I must delete the existing database and redo the seed?

Comment: If you didn't do the migration correctly and there more changes then that are defined in your code for the migration to work correctly, you might find that you have to drop the DB and then run "update-Database". Don't forget to BACKUP your database or export your data!

Answer (score 1):

@anAgent has you covered for the answer here. I want to give you more information on what's happening here, so you can understand *why* those steps are necessary.

In order to generate migrations, Entity Framework creates a `_MigrationHistory` table that tracks the state of your application's entities. Each time a migration is run, a new row is added to this table with a hashed version of the schema at that point. When starting up, Entity Framework uses this stored state to compare with the current state of your entities, and if they don't match, you get that error telling you that you the model backing as changed. That means that in order for your application code to be able to work with the underlying database, schema modifications need to be made or there will be SQL errors.

What you've done is manually made the appropriate changes to your database, which is enough to make the application function properly. However, since this `_MigrationHistory` table still has the old state as the latest state, Entity Framework still thinks that the schema needs to be updated. Again, it's not looking at the current state of your database; it's looking at the state of the database after the last successful migration.

What all that boils down to is you must either:

1. Follow @anAgent's advice and actually use a migration to make the changes instead of manually altering your schema, always.
2. Remove the `_MigrationHistory` table and continue to manually update your schema. If this table doesn't exist, Entity Framework effectively treats the database as an existing database and won't ever run migrations against it or even prompt you to. However, this puts the ball *entirely* in your court. You will be 100% responsible for managing the schema, and if you make changes to the application and neglect to also update the database schema appropriately, the application will raise SQL error exceptions.

Comment: I've added to my DBContext Migration AddColumn_Gasto, and now then I should add to my class poco (in my model) this columns, no? ... Then I have this error

Comment: I run the Midration with 'Update-Database', my DB it´s OK with my news columns, and Then I add this columns in my class-model poco .. CRASH!!

Comment: If I understand you properly, your order or ops is off. Make changes to your POCO, *then* generate and apply a migration. If you make more changes after migrating, then you need to migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

If your model change in some point you need also change your database schema. As the exception suggests, it’s time to start using [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).You need to set the database initializer in the context class with the new db initialization strategy `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` as shown below:

```
    public class YourContext: DbContext 
    {
        public YourContext(): base("DefaultConnectionString") 
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, YourProject.Migrations.Configuration>("DefaultConnectionString"));    
        }
    }
```

Now, you have two options:

- [Automated Migration](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx)

  You run your application and you will always get your database in the latest version because EF will do implicit migration every time it is needed - in the purest version you never need to do anything more than enabling automatic migrations

  If you enabled migrations correctly you should also have a folder called *Migrations* and inside it a `Configuration` class, its constructor should look like this (if you want to enable automatic migrations):

  ```
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
  }
  ```
- [Code-base Migration](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx)

  If you turn off automatic migrations you must always define explicit migration to define database upgrading process in well defined explicit steps. This is especially useful for scenarios where you need to use both upgrading and downgrading to specific version.In this case, you need to use `Add-Migration` command to write this change out to a code-based migration so that you can edit it. The `Add-Migration` command allows you to give these migrations a name, for example `Add-Migration AddSomeProperty`.After execute that command,in the *Migrations* folder you will have a new migration file, whose name is pre-fixed with a timestamp to help with ordering.

Comment: I created my db and is full of data, but I have realized that I want to add a field more to one of my tables. How I keep the data that I have stuck?

Comment: If you use for example Automated Migration, the `Configuration` class has a property called `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` whose default value is false. So in case that you are going to change someting that provoke some inconsistency regarding to your database schema and it could end in data loss, an exception will be throw. If this exception is not thrown, you don't have to worry about loss your data, it will remain intact in your DB

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have following statement somewhere in your application :

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<InterstoneContext>());
```

In this case it will recreate the db if it does not exist. There is also one like this :

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<InterstoneContext>());
```

The second one will verify that your db has changed. This is what seems to be happening with you. If you disable this, the verification will not happen.
You changed the db, and you changed your code, so migration is not needed if I understand you correctly.But the above statements or any setinitialiser has to be commented out.

Answer (score -2):

The error message says exactly what you need do "using code first migrations to generate the change script".

Comment: The error: "The model backing the 'xxxxxDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
"

Comment: If you don't want to keep the data, then just drop the database in your local environment. If you want to keep your data, then follow the suggestion by anAgent.

Comment: I.e. have I to make a tool to keep my data?

Comment: You can script your data into "insert" statement.

Comment: Yes, but I have to read all data in my all database and generate a new database, no???