# ASP.NET MVC Update Model and Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC, but I have worked with code-first migrations on some basic tables.

My model is as follows

```
public class sp_Result {    
    [Key]
    public string RowDesc { get; set; }
    public string rowkey { get; set; }
    public int rowlevel { get; set; }
    public int Plan { get; set; }
}
```

And this is generated by a stored procedure in my controller

```
public ActionResult StaffPage()
{
    var startlevel = new SqlParameter("rlevel",10);            

    var staffing = db.Database.SqlQuery<sp_Result>("exec sp_MyStoredProcedure @rlevel", startlevel);
    return View(staffing);
}
```

So I needed to add the field "Plan" and updated my model and stored procedure that generates this info accordingly. However, now I am getting the lovely "The model backing the ' context has changed since the database was created" error. Is there a way to get these to sync, as I am not really looking to update a table, so I'm not entirely sure Code-first is the way to go? I saw here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507636/if-change-model-class-in-dbcontext-do-i-rebuild-the-database that I can delete the _MigrationHistory table and that would make it work, but I am hesitant to do that.

I should add that this is a non-local database (if that matters). Is there a way to sync my model to my stored procedure output?

Comment: have you called `add-migration` then `update-database` in your package manager console?

Comment: Every time I try to `Enable-Migrations` for this particular DBContext, it locks up my system. Also, is `update-database` valid for the results of a stored procedure and not an editable table? All i have seen are Up/Down functions that rewrite the entire SP

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just deleted the _MigrationHistory table. Fixed it.